# warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specification

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

When I porting source code from VC++6 to VC++9 with visual studio 2008, I have this warning:

```
warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specification
```

I don't how to fix this warning. Please can somebody help me? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/EDITANDCONTINUE` feature allows you to edit the code in the debugger and if it compiles and links, continue.

The `/OPT` flags are optimisations. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx) If the code has been optimised it cannot let you edit and continue.

To stop the warning turn one off, or the other. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574367/lnk4075-ignoring-editandcontinue-due-to-opticf-specification)